# Symfony Form Customization Issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I've styled my form by hand using Bootstrap 3 and now I'm experiencing a bottleneck implementing expanded radio buttons.

The original templates looks like this

```
{% block choice_widget_expanded %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
        {% for child in form %}
           {{ form_widget(child) }}
           {{ form_label(child) }}
        {% endfor %}
       </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_expanded %}
```

How do I parse the child element to be able to do something like this

```
<label>{{ form_widget(child) }} {{child label}}</label>
```

I've tried dumping the child array to see which key stores the label without much success and since it's a single frontend form, didn't see it worth installing whole bootstrap bundles

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, for anyone out there who might be struggling with this,

```
{{ form_label(child, child.vars.label|trans({}, translation_domain)) }}
```